# How to compare diagonally opposed element of a multidimensional array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a non-symmetrical matrix and basically I would like to compare diagonally opposed element as follow:

- if the diagonally opposed element are equal but opposed in sign, keep the absolute value of an element and zero the diagonally opposed value
- if it is not the case, then one of the two element is 0 (but we don't know which one), so take the absolute value of both.

Once this is done transpose the lower triangle of the matrix and add it to the upper triangle.

I came up with the following python loop:

```
for i in range(0, number_files):
    for j in range(0, len(Identifier)):
        for k in range(0,len(Identifier)):
            if Matrix[i][j][k] == - Matrix[i][k][j]: 
                Matrix[i][j][k] = abs(Matrix[i][j][k]) 
                Matrix[i][k][j] = 0                
            else:
                Matrix[i][j][k] = abs(Matrix[i][j][k]) # one of this two
                Matrix[i][k][j] = abs(Matrix[i][k][j]) # values is 0
    Matrix[i] = np.tril(Matrix[i],0).transpose() + np.triu(Matrix[i],0)
```

However, this is very slow and I was wondering how I could improve it with numpy.

I know I can generate a test for example with:

```
test=np.isclose(Matrix.transpose(),-Matrix)
```

which will return a boolean matrix, but I do not know how to proceed with that.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start by creating a sample matrix:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(-3, 3, 100).reshape(10,10)
```

Getting its upper and lower triangles:

```
>>> triu = np.triu(a)
>>> tril = np.tril(a)
```

Note that `triu` and `tril` are the same size as `a`, but filled with zeros outside the triangle.

Define the triangle you want to modify, and transpose the other. E.g. modify upper triangle:

```
>>> tril = tril.T
```

As you suggested, do one of the following to create a mask where your condition applies:

```
# For integer data
>>> mask = (triu == -tril) & (triu != 0)
# For real data
>>> mask = np.isclose(triu, -tril) & ~np.isclose(triu, 0)
```

Note the new condition added (`!= 0`), to avoid comparisons comparisons where `triu` and `tril` are filled with `0`. `mask` will contain `True` where an element from the upper triangle `triu` matches lower triangle `tril`.

Implement your conditions:

```
# Second and abs part of the first condition
>>> a = np.abs(a)
# Set upper diagonal when matches lower diagonal to 0
>>> a[mask] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much iluengo for your solution. Could you please explain why you chose to use the ~ operator for the ~np.isclose(triu,0)? Many thanks

Comment: When using a boolean array, ~ negates the array (it has the same behaviour as !, but for negating a whole boolean matrix). `~mask = not mask = !mask` but since in this case `mask` is a multidimensional numpy array, the first one ~ is the only one that works.